# Using a variable in complete event of AJAX method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using an iteration for, and in the complete event of AJAX I'm trying to use iteration variable i.

But in all iterations it always equals 4?
Why 4? I expected 2 then 3, but received 4.

```
for (i=2; i<=3; i++) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('ajax/GetData') ?>",
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "country":$('[name=country]').val(),
            "currency":$('[name=currency]').val(),
            "system_id":i
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {

            addEventClick();
        },
        complete: function() {

            if (i-1 == 3) {
                $('[name=data_input]').addClass('hidden');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Because when the AJAX call finishes, the loop has long since completed its run leaving `i` at `4`.

Answer (score 1):

`success` and `complate` are both callback functions that is invoked when the asynchronous ajax request has finished and at that time the for loop has already completed.

You could have your response return the `system_id` value and then use it in your `success` handler;

```
success: function (data, textStatus) {
  addEventClick();

  if (data.system_id == 2) {
    $('[name=data_input]').addClass('hidden');
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess, that I need to change my dataType from html to json?

Comment: Yes, that´s correct. As you are not using the response for anything else.